# Creating MS Office setup

Tags: microsoft-office, setup, installer, microsoft-office-2016

I have two computers
I have MS Office 2016 installed in one computer. I want to install it in the another computer.
**My Questions:** 1) Can i create a setup of MS Office using the existing installation so that i can install it in  the sencond computer?
2) Is there any Software to do so?

Comment: Do you have an Office licence for more than one computer? How was it installed on the first computer?

Comment: If you don't have the installation content, it will be very difficult to copy each file of Office from one of your PC with Office installed, as during installation the setup copy those files to various directories.

Comment: Actually I have a dual boot pc , i tried copying the whole microsoft office folder from program files but that's not working

Comment: That is Microsoft-piracy and they don't want you to do that.